# How to reuse GraphQL interface description

Tags: graphql

Assume I have the following GraphQL SDL:

```
interface Person {
  # describes how the person is called
  name: String
}

type Student implements Person {
  # describes how the person is called
  name: String
}
```

How can I reuse/avoid duplication of the comment line?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using GraphQL.js, if your type definitions are defined using a template literal, you can just do something like:

```
const personComment = '# describes how the person is called'

const typeDefs = `
interface Person {
  ${personComment}
  name: String
}

type Student implements Person {
  ${personComment}
  name: String
}
`
```

If you're importing a `gql` file, you may have to get more creative and use a library like `string-template`.

You can use the same approach for reducing duplication of fields (across a type and its corresponding input type, for example). For what it's worth, though, you may find that doing this reduces the readability of your schema and may not be worth it just to keep things DRY.